# Scroll to top functionality not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, mediawiki

I am using this

```
$(function() {
  $('<button onclick="topFunction()" id="topBtn" title="Go to top"></button>').insertAfter('div#mw-content-text');
});

// When users scroll down 100px, show the Top button
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 100 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
    document.getElementById("topBtn").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("topBtn").style.display = "none";
  }
}

// When users click on Top button, scroll up
function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

Which works fine on all browsers apart from Firefox. In this case, it is displayed in the middle of the screen and does not stick at the bottom right when scrolling.

The css I use is this:

```
#topBtn {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 99;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
#topBtn:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
#topBtn:before {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 2px;
    right: 36px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 42px;
    font-family: 'Georgia';
    content: "^";
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

Reference page: https://lsj.gr/wiki/%CE%BB%CE%BF%CF%8D%CF%89

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `position: fixed;` to the button. Then you can position it with `left`, `right`, `bottom` and `top`.

```js
$(function() {
  $('<button onclick="topFunction()" id="topBtn" title="Go to top">Click</button>').insertAfter('div#mw-content-text');
});
```

```css
#mw-content-text {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: green;
}

#topBtn {
  position: fixed;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mw-content-text"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, how exactly should I change the code? I.e. find x, replace y.

Comment: Remove the 2 lines inside `topFunction()` and add `window.scrollTo(0,0)`

Comment: Thanks. That does not affect the positioning in the middle of the page in FF (as defined in scrollFunction)

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood your question completely. Let me update my answer.

Comment: I updated the answer with the css I use. `position: fixed;` was there already.

Comment: When I replicate the code in a codepen(https://codepen.io/jelmerovereem/pen/gOoBeBV) and view it on firefox, the button is showing nicely at the bottom right. Can you maybe make a codepen where you replicate your issue? Maybe some other code is interfering?

Comment: Well, it works just fine in all other browsers, the point is for it to work on the specific website and I cannot see any relevant errors on my console anyway. As for codepen, maybe because there is no content to scroll through the page it affects the way it shows.

Comment: I figured it out, the `<html>` tag has a `filter` on it, if you disable that. The button will show correctly. I see the navigation will also show correctly.
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1418866

Comment: Yes, that fixed it.